# tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score can not be imported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to calculate the F1 score using tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score, but it gives me an error. I know how to calculate it using precision and recall but i want to use this function.

I have tried it on ubuntu 16.04 LTS with tensorflow version 1.9.0 with gpu suport and no gpu suport

```
from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import f1_score as ms
```

i get this error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call   last)
<ipython-input-6-627f14191ea2> in <module>()----> 1 from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import  f1_score as ms

ImportError: cannot import name 'f1_score'
```

AND

```
from tensorflow.contrib import metrics as ms
ms.f1_score
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c19f57465581> in <module>()
1 from tensorflow.contrib import metrics as ms
----> 2 ms.f1_score

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.metrics' has no attribute 'f1_score'
```

I expect ms.f1_score would load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you have `tf.contrib` available and this doesn't work for you, maybe you will need to reinstall tensorflow use `pip install -U tensorflow` or use the -GPU if you are using that version.

If it fails, go to the place where tensorflow is installed and manually check if it is available or not, if it is available, make sure that you don't have a file in the same directory (Current working directory) named as tensorflow.py or tf.py

After that you should get
[image: Proper loading Image]

Update: As pointed by User @grwlf

Since TensorFlow 2.0, tf.contrib modules were moved to the Addons repo. See github.com/tensorflow/addons. There, F1 mesure is available as F1Score from `tensorflow_addons.metrics import F1Score`

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, btw you have spelled tensorflow wrong, thinking about future references.

Comment: Since TensorFlow 2.0, `tf.contrib` modules were moved to the Addons repo. See https://github.com/tensorflow/addons. There, F1 mesure is available as `F1Score`
`from tensorflow_addons.metrics import F1Score`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation of f1_score [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/f1_score)

Since it is a function, maybe you can try out:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import metrics as ms
ms.f1_score(labels,predictions)
```

Which will return a scalar tensor of the best f1 scores across different thresholds.

Example from tensorflow docs:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    predictions = make_predictions(features)
    loss = make_loss(predictions, labels) 
    train_op = tf.contrib.training.create_train_op( total_loss=loss, optimizer='Adam') 
    eval_metric_ops = {'f1': f1_score(labels, predictions)} 
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec( mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops, export_outputs=export_outputs) 

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
```

Hope this answers your question.